# How to rotate a line(x1=50,y1=50,x2=50,y2=10) with respect to x=50,y=50 as center using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's something like rotation around z-axis. Came to know about transform-origin but its accepting in % that's not working for me. Kindly assist

Comment: How is the line drawn? Where is your code? What have you tried? Can you provide us with a simplified code that points out what isn't working? Have you done your due diligence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to transform an SVG line using CSS. Unfortunately, that's not going to be cross-browser compatible. The non-cross-browser compatible version takes a px value and treats it like an SVG unit. You can do this:

```
transform: rotate(30deg);
transform-origin: 50px 50px;
```

However, to be cross-browser compatible, you have to do your transform inside your SVG line:

```
<line x1="50" x2="50" y1="50" y2="10" transform="rotate(30 50 50)" />
```

This is rotating it 30 degrees around the point 50, 50. Hope that helps.

Comment: Great it worked. I not used px for transform-origin center. I just used numbers like coordinates of line.